# php CURL not working with dynamic URLs

Tags: php, curl, get, dynamic-url

I can't work out why this URL is not being found by CURL. The CURL engine is simply taken to a 400 error page.

My code is very simple and works fantastically with non-dynamic URLs.

I am hoping it's something easy to spot, for example, a missing CURL option.

I have tried using $url = urlencode($url) but that didn't work either.

Here's the code:

```
$url = 'http://www.destinations-uk.com/accommodations.php?link=accommodations&country=england&category=Reviews&id=1';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,            $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,         true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY,         true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        15);
$r = curl_exec($ch);
$r = explode("\n", $r);
$keys = array();
if(!empty($r)) $keys[] = array_shift($r);
foreach($r as $line){
    preg_match('/.+:\s/',$line,$match);
    if($match) $keys[substr($match[0],0,-2)] = preg_replace('/.+:\s/','', $line);
}
print_r($keys);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps, this is something on the server-side done to prevent automated requests.

Comment: I think you must be right - it works great with a google based dynamic URL. Thanks!